# Read username from smart card with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, smartcard

I am working on a web-application that runs on a Tomcat 7 server. I want to make the site accessible via a smart card, so I made the clientAuth="true" change in the Tomcat server.xml.

I can access the web-app with a smart card now, but I want to be able to read the username/alias from the smart card in my web-app. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Also, do modern browsers take care of CRL checking when a site requests client auth?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implemenent an [`X509UsernameRetriever`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/catalina/authenticator/SSLAuthenticator.html) and pass the class name to [this method](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/RealmBase.html#setX509UsernameRetrieverClassName(java.lang.String)) of your realm. The realm should do the rest. I guess you are after the [`subjectAltName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectAlternativeNames%28%29) field to retrieve UPN of the user.